# Can't read CSV file in using FileUpload in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, file-upload

On one of my WebPages I have placed FileUpload1 item, in which I would like to store CSV file and then analyze it. However I can't read it in, an Exception is thrown. It seems like the filepath changes (I have file store on Desktop, whereas it displays that the file is searched in C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express).

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs 
{


        Response.Write("Jestem w petli file.hasfile");
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
        {
            string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            string[] readLines = new string[7];
            int dayOfWeek = 0;

            while (dayOfWeek < 7)
            {
                do
                {
                    string textLine = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    readLines[dayOfWeek] = textLine;                      
                }
                while (reader.Peek() != -1);

                dayOfWeek++;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                generateData(readLines[i], i);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            TableRow tblRow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(tblRow);

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                tCell.Text = positionsInWtr[i, j];
                tblRow.Cells.Add(tCell);                
            }
        }
    }
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Kokos

Comment: You have to save file before reading it. Check sample here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

                string savePath = @"c:\temp\uploads\";

                savePath += fileName;
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);

Says that can't find part of the path: „c:\temp\uploads\dupa.csv”

Comment: a) Does c:\temp\uploads\ really exsists? b) Does you IIS Express process have access to it?

Comment: a) It exists, however it had no write access. Thanks.
b) Yes. It was opened with Administrator privileges.